# Helm configmap value from existing secret

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I have an existing `secret` named `setspace-db-secret` and i want to fetch a value from one of its keys named `db-root-password` to the `configmap`, so i wrote a basic lookup function like below in `_helpers.tpl`

```
{{- define "getpassword" }}
{{- $obj := (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Namespace .Name).data -}}
{{- index $obj .Key | b64dec -}}
{{- end }}
```

and then did this in the `configmap`

```
password: {{- include "getpassword" (dict "Namespace" .Release.Namespace "Name" "setspace-db-secret" "Key" "db-root-password")  -}}
```

and i am getting the below error

```
error calling include: template: mynew/templates/_helpers.tpl:2:34: executing "getpassword" at <index $obj .Key>: error calling index: index of untyped nil
```

Is my approach wrong? what am i missing here. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: That looks to me like `$obj` is nil, maybe the Secret doesn't exist?  (I might pass the value directly as a Helm value rather than using `lookup` and hoping another tool has already set the value in the cluster.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{{- define "getpassword" -}}
{{- $obj := (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Namespace .Name).data -}}
{{- $data := index $obj .Key | b64dec -}}
{{- printf "%s" $data -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working. ` include "getpassword" (dict "Namespace" .Release.Namespace "Name" "my-secret" "Key" "keyvalue") `,  but got error - `executing "getpassword" at <.Release.Namespace>: can't evaluate field Release in type string`